# Grease on an ice elemental

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, monsters

Can an ice elemental slip and fall from the level 1 spell Grease?

The description for ice elementals state that they can't be tripped, but does the effect of the grease spell actually count as being tripped? Or is it just a generic ruling in that they can never fall prone?

I think that RAW the creature has a chance to fall, but RAI it makes sense otherwise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, RAW, elementals can be knocked prone.

Being Tripped and falling down are different, so immunity to Trip doesn't mean there's no way make them prone.

There is nothing else in the Ice Elemental entry that suggests they are immune to being prone, and other elementals (I referenced Water and Fire) don't even have Trip immunity. It seems that Ice elementals are Medusa-like in shape, and their 'snake' tail allows them to avoid being tripped.

Don't be surprised if your GM narrates them not being prone though, because elementals are portrayed as beings of just their element, with no sensory organs and no 'need' to be 'upright'.

Answer (score 5):

Trip is a specific combat maneuver that is defended against using CMD. Grease requires a Reflex save to avoid falling. They're mechanically completely separate, so the elemental's immunity to trip doesn't help them here. That said, as a GM, it wouldn't be unreasonable to say that a snake-like elemental (or other non-walking creature) will never slip on Grease, especially if the elemental is larger than the area of the Grease spell. I don't believe there are any RAW for this case, though.